# Verificar quantidade de vagas disponíveis - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fullcalendar

Olá, tenho duas tabelas :
beneficios_reserva (id_beneficios_reserva, data_reserva, associado_reserva);
beneficios_calendario (id_beneficios_calendario, start, color);

Estou usando o fullcalendar, o meu problema está sendo no foreach, pois eu queria mostrar a quantidade uma unica vez.

```
public function vagas_disponiveis() 
{   
    $data = array();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('beneficios_calendario');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $dia = $query->result_array();

    $this->db->select('count(*) as cnt, data_reserva');
    $this->db->from('beneficios_reserva');
    $this->db->group_by('data_reserva');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $reservas = $query->result_array();

    $vagas = '30';
    $disp = '';

    foreach ($dia as $simi) {

        foreach ($reservas as $reserva) 
        {
            if ($simi['start'] == $reserva['data_reserva']) {
                $disp = $vagas - $reserva["cnt"];
                $data[] = array(
                    'title'   => $disp,
                    'start'   => $reserva["data_reserva"],
                    'color'   => $simi["color"]
                );
            }else{
                $data[] = array(
                    'title'   => $vagas,
                    'start'   => $simi["start"],
                    'color'   => $simi["color"]
                );
            }
        }

    }

    echo json_encode($data);
```

}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tenho 30 vagas por dia, eu quero que ele mostre somente um campo, por exemplo se não há reserva fique 30, caso haja reserva ele mostre as vagas restantes, caso alguém reservou 8 vagas ele mostre somente 22 restantes.

**EDIT**

Atualização do model Victor

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('beneficios_calendario');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $dias = $query->result_array(); // Note que alterei o nome da variável

    $this->db->select('count(*) as cnt, data_reserva');
    $this->db->from('beneficios_reserva');
    $this->db->group_by('data_reserva');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $reservas = $query->result_array();

    $data = array();
    $limite = 30; // Limite de vagas por dia

    // Criando o array com valores padronizados
    foreach ($dias as $dia) {
        $data[] = array(
            'title' => $limite,
            'start' => $dia['start'],
            'color' => $dia['color']
        );
    }

    // Alterando a quantidade de reservas de acordo com a data
    foreach ($reservas as $reserva) {
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            if ($row['start'] == $reserva['data_reserva']) {
                $row['title'] = $row['title'] - $reserva['cnt']
            }
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alterando o segundo foreach

```
// Criando o array com valores padronizados
    foreach ($dias as $dia) {
        $data[] = array(
            'title' => $limite,
            'start' => $dia['start'],
            'color' => $dia['color']
        );
    }

    // Alterando a quantidade de reservas de acordo com a data
    foreach ($reservas as $reserva) {
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            if ($row['start'] == $reserva['data_reserva']) {
                $row['title'] = $row['title'] - $reserva['cnt'];
                $data[] = array(
                    'title' =>  $row['title'],
                    'start' => $row['start'],
                    'color' => $row['color']
                );
            }
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
```

preciso do formato

```
$data[] = array(
                    'title'   => title, //30 ou XX vagas restantes
                    'start'   => data,
                    'color'   => color
                );
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não consegui entender o seu real problema ainda... Pode explicar mais detalhadamente, por favor?

Comment: eu quero que apareça somente um valor, tipo dia 22/09 30 vagas, caso alguem agende por exemplo 5 vagas, ele apareça somente com 25 disponível, me desculpe se não ficou claro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução: fiz um foreach contando a data de reserva e depois fiz um update na tabela calendário e depois eu pego todos da tabela calendário o mostro os dados.

```
public function vagas_disponiveis() 
{

    $this->db->select('count(*) as cnt, data_reserva');
    $this->db->from('beneficios_reserva');
    $this->db->group_by('data_reserva');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $reservas = $query->result_array();

    if (!empty($reservas))
    {
        foreach ($reservas as $reserva) 
        {
            $title = 30 - $reserva['cnt'];
            $new = array(
                'title' => $title,
            );

            $this->db->where('start', $reserva['data_reserva']);
            $this->db->set($new);
            $atual = $this->db->update('beneficios_calendario', $new);
        }   
    }

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('beneficios_calendario');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $dias = $query->result_array();

    $data = array();

    foreach ($dias as $dia) {
        $data[] = array(
            'title' => $dia['title'],
            'start' => $dia['start'],
            'color' => $dia['color']
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($data);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
public function vagas_disponiveis() 
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('beneficios_calendario');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $dias = $query->result_array(); // Note que alterei o nome da variável

    $this->db->select('count(*) as cnt, data_reserva');
    $this->db->from('beneficios_reserva');
    $this->db->group_by('data_reserva');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $reservas = $query->result_array();

    $data = array();
    $limite = 30; // Limite de vagas por dia

    // Criando o array com valores padronizados
    foreach ($dias as $dia) {
        $data[] = array(
            'title' => $limite,
            'start' => $dia['start'],
            'color' => $dia['color']
        );
    }

    // Alterando a quantidade de reservas de acordo com a data
    foreach ($reservas as $reserva) {
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            if ($row['start'] == $reserva['data_reserva']) {
                $row['title'] = $row['title'] - $reserva['cnt'];
            }
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Victor deu certo, só que não mostrou no calendario meu js, editei a pergunta e coloquei o codigo js.

$data[] = array(
      'title'   => $vagas,
      'start'   => $simi["start"],
      'color'   => $simi["color"]
     );
era assim

Comment: Victor me perdoe por não responder antes, a estrutura do JS está na pergunta. Acredito que o problema seja no $data[$dataReserva]['title'] que traz um int()  
$(data).each(function (index, d) {
                        events.push({
                            title: d.title,
                            start: d.start,
                            color: d.color
                        });
                    });

Comment: como faço a alteração? estou lendo https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Comment: deu certo com sua atualização, porem só está mostrando os dias que tem reserva, os outros dias que não tem reserva (30) não aparece, vou tentar arrumar e já posto

Comment: Atualizei a resposta novamente. Creio que o problema será resolvido com essa atualização que fiz.

Comment: atualizei a pergunta, coloquei na tabela uma coluna title com o valor de 30, assim não precisa do limite

Comment: existe a possibilidade de manter nesse formato $data[] = array(
    'title' => $dia['title'],
    'start' => $dia['start'],
    'color' => $dia['color']
   );